# Is it possible to use OfType in a linq where?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table called source that has multiple derived tables such as account, etc. I have a second table that has a navigation property to that table called Source.

What I'd like to do is filter the results of ActionItemState by the type of the Source then filter based on a property of that inherited table.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.  I get ". LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types" when I try the code below.  Does anyone know of a way to use OfType or something similar?

```
 query = from a in _actionItemRepository.GetTable()
         where a.ActionItemStates.Any(ais => ais.Source is AccountSource && ((AccountSource)ais.Source).AccountId == id)
         select a;
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try going the other way with it:

```
var accountSources = db.Sources.OfType<AccountSource>();
var actionItemStates = accountSources.SelectMany(a => a.ActionItemStates);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
Source.OfType<AccountSource>()
```

You apply before Where operator

```
 OfType<AccountSource>().Where(....)
```